# Hover menu with no proper text alignment

Tags: html, css

With reference to this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vMuxA/).

The text of menu items are not left alligned properly...
when i try with my code...

above is what i get[image]

Below is my css

```
* {font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma;}
ul.nav {border-bottom: 1px solid #999;}
ul.nav li a {display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #333; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav > li:hover {border: 1px solid #666; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav li a:hover {background: #ccc; border: 1px solid #999;}
ul.nav > li {display: inline-block; position: relative; border: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav > li ul {display: none; position: absolute; left: -1px; width: 150px; border: 1px solid #666; border-top-color: #fff; margin-top: 1px;   
background: #939393;}

ul.nav > li:hover ul {display: block;}
ul.nav > li ul li {display: block;}
```

& HTML code.....

```
<body>
<ul class="nav">
<li> <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li> <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li> <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>

<div id="container-inside"> <a href="#">Tab1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#">Tab2</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#">Tab3</a> </div>
```

Comment: and also how do i get rid off the lines within menu items...

Comment: sorry for a lengthy code.... actually this is bugging me for more than an hour...

Comment: Looks good to me. What browser are you viewing this in?

Comment: chrome.... but dude will that affect... just now checked with firefox.. but the result is same...

Comment: Again, I'm seeing it just fine with Chrome. So I can't reproduce the issue. The jsFiddle looks good to me.

Comment: are you getting the submenu right below the parent menu...

Comment: This is how it looks using your code: http://jsfiddle.net/dr_lucas/vMuxA/392/ looks fine here on latest IE, Chrome and FF. Does it look right to you? if not, which browser are you using?

Comment: why is it tagged with php ?

Comment: right, got nothing to do with PHP, you can edit his post and remove the tag...

Comment: @CreativeMind im using chrome, checked on FF aswell.. and im on xp sp3... will that be any difference...

Comment: not that I know of, should work just fine. which chrome version are you using? did you try another browser? how does the fiddle I posted look? same problem?

Comment: just now updated FF to the latest ver... but no change...

Comment: what about my fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/dr_lucas/vMuxA/392/

Comment: sorry.. its the same problem... anyways thanks all of you.. for sparing ur time....

Comment: let me try this on another box....may be on win7...